# Show math symbols on winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, latex, symbols

I would like to include formulas in some labels on winforms. Since these formulas can get quite complex i would ideally need some third party library to parse LaTeX code and print the result.

I am quite surprised that i did not find anything like this yet since i would imagine that this is not an uncommon requirement. Is there another 'way to go' in .NET to include non-standard symbols and change their size & positioning?

Are there more/other possibilities to accomplish this for WPF?

Comment: You could use [utf characters](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html)

Comment: I hoped that i can avoid that since those don't look very good and are very hard to read in large formulas (imagine something like \int_a^b (LaTeX notation) or even a simple quotient of integral formulas with greek letters). Also since i would need to manually resize and adapt the position for all symbols individually for a proper representation, i hoped that this does exist in form of a library already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fMath](http://www.fmath.info/java/download.jsp) is a LaTeX implementation for C# WinForms in .NET 4 for x86/x64. It's distributed under the Apache License.